# wxpython DrawText returns with error

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am trying to have the text that is typed in my control variable drawn onto the rectangle I made in shapeRectangle. Every time I run the program, type in some text and press enter it does not print what I typed onto the rectangle and also while I am here I guess I might as well ask if any of you know how to change the color of the text? Instead it returns with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\client with gui.py", line 39, in SendPress
    wx.DrawText(self.shapeRectangle, self.sent, 0, 300 )
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DrawText'




import socket
import wx

class WindowFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size=(500, 400))
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("#0B3861")
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE, size =(410, 28), pos=(0,329))

        # Sets up the socket connection
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 6667
        self.s.connect((host,port))

        # creates send button and binds to event
        sendbutton=wx.Button(self.panel, label ="Send", pos =(414,325), size=(65,35))
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SendPress, sendbutton )

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        #Draws white rectangle
    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)  # <<< This was changed
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('black'))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('white'))
        self.shapeRectangle=dc.DrawRectangle(20, 20, 444, 280)
        self.Show(True)


        # Sets the function of the send button
    def SendPress(self, event):
        self.sent = self.control.GetValue()
        self.s.send(self.sent)
        self.control.Clear()
        wx.DrawText(self.shapeRectangle, self.sent, 0, 300 )
        self.s.close()

if __name__=="__main__": 
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = WindowFrame(None, 'ChatClient')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: supposed to be `dc.DrawText()`.

Comment: @ohad `dc.DrawText` will not work

Comment: It would have been uselful if it said that on the site

Comment: yeah I just tried it and it didnt :(

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Why not? because `dc` is not global object in `WindowFrame`? I noticed that. fix me if I wrong ofcourse.

Comment: @ohad, yes the dc instance is in the onPaint method. You would have to create another PaintDC instance  in the sendPress method to use it.

Comment: @user3768136 Just declare the `dc` object at the `WindowFrame` class with `self`. (Make it global variable)

Comment: @Ohad can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.

```
import socket
import wx

class WindowFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size=(500, 400))
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("#0B3861")
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE, size =(410, 28), pos=(0,329))
        self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)  # <<< This was changed
        # Sets up the socket connection
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 6667
        self.s.connect((host,port))

        # creates send button and binds to event
        sendbutton=wx.Button(self.panel, label ="Send", pos =(414,325), size=(65,35))
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SendPress, sendbutton )

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        #Draws white rectangle
    def OnPaint(self, event):
        self.dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('black'))
        self.dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('white'))
        self.shapeRectangle=self.dc.DrawRectangle(20, 20, 444, 280)
        self.Show(True)


        # Sets the function of the send button
    def SendPress(self, event):
        self.sent = self.control.GetValue()
        self.s.send(self.sent)
        self.control.Clear()
        self.dc.DrawText(self.sent, 0, 300 )
        self.s.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = WindowFrame(None, 'ChatClient')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: `wx.DC.DrawText` gets 4 parameters: `(self, text, x, y)`, `self.shapeRectangle` is not necessary, and it won't work.

Comment: @ohad, I used the OP's code which had defined `DrawText` which I presumed had the correct parameters. The issue was accessing the DrawText method. What error are you getting?

Comment: @Ohad, no worries, I presumed the OP had actually used the correct parameters.

Comment: @Ohad Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\client with gui.py", line 40, in SendPress
    self.dc.DrawText(self.shapeRectangle, self.sent, 0, 300 )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_gdi.py", line 3823, in DrawText
    return _gdi_.DC_DrawText(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: DC_DrawText() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)

Comment: @Ohad Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\client with gui.py", line 44, in <module>
    frame = WindowFrame(None, 'ChatClient')
  File "C:\Python27\client with gui.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)  # <<< This was changed
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_gdi.py", line 5215, in __init__
    _gdi_.PaintDC_swiginit(self,_gdi_.new_PaintDC(*args, **kwargs))
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ..\..\src\msw\dcclient.cpp(277) in wxPaintDCImpl::wxPaintDCImpl(): wxPaintDCImpl may be created only in EVT_PAINT hand

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham It keeps returning the error for me

Comment: which error, just paste the last line not the while output

Comment: @PadraicCunningham PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ..\..\src\msw\dcclient.cpp(277) in wxPaintDCImpl::wxPaintDCImpl(): wxPaintDCImpl may be created only in EVT_PAINT handler!